# Составной первичный ключ или GUID

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, таблицы, нормализация-данных

Работая с одной базой данных столкнулся со следующим примером.

Допустим у нас есть база данных библиотеки (пример из реальной базы привести не могу по соображениям коммерческой тайны).

Пусть есть таблица Book, где первичный ключ является составным (**подход № 1**):

- id библиотеки, где хранится книга
- id справочника, к которому относится книга
- id книги

При этом id библиотеки встречается во многих других таблицах как составная часть первичного ключа.

С моей точки зрения можно было бы использовать в качестве первичного ключа GUID (**подход № 2**), а id библиотеки и id справочника использовать как составной внешний ключ.

Какие плюсы и минусы двух представленных выше подходов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В подобных случаях я практически всегда выбираю вариант, использующий суррогатный уникальный ключ - иногда это GUID, а иногда просто целый счетчик (sequence, identity, auto_increment) для каждой таблицы.

Вот несколько причин в пользу этого подхода:

- гарантия уникальности
- нет необходимости изменения первичного ключа в случае изменения одной из составляющих композитного ключа (например книга "переехала" из одной библиотеки в другую или `id` справочника поменялось)
- при изменении модели данных может пондобиться в будущем добавлять компоненты (столбцы) к композитному ключу - опять же изменение первичного ключа, которое может иметь каскадный эффект на таблицы ссылающиеся на данный первичный ключ

из минусов:

- дополнительное место (на диске и в памяти) для хранения суррогатного ключа
- если использовать GUID вместо обычного целого число, то иногда они генерируются таким образом, что меняется часть строки в середине, а не в конце строки. Это вызывает "размазывание" значений индекса по разным индексным блокам (это зависит от реализации СУБД). В итоге приложения, которые работают в основном с последними поступившими данными (финансовые транзакции, заказы, etc.) будут работать с б**О**льшим количеством "размазанных" индексных блоков. **NOTE:** в SQL Server можно воспользоваться [NEWSEQUENTIALID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), который, судя по описанию, минимизирует эффект "размазывания".

Comment: По поводу последнего пункта: некоторые СУБД имеют средства для устранения такого негативного эффекта. Например, в SqlServer вместо NEWID можно использовать [NEWSEQUENTIALID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Думаю, вы это знаете, но почему бы не добавить инфы новичкам.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо! добавил в ответ...

Comment: Большое спасибо за совет, но мне больше нравится генерировать Guid из программы)